# How to disable pinentry-qt in fedora 20 for git-svn ?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, password-encryption

I use git-svn command line client to synchronize my projects to an svn repository. 
Since I moved to fedora 20 (I was on fedora 17 before), when I synchronize with the svn repository (with git svn rebase, for instance) I have, very often, a  pinentry-qt window pop-up. 
  The  pinentry-qt popup message looks like "Enter your Subversion password for  2bb3333-jhgw3jkh23-abac-9e876hjid".  If I enter a password it asks me to enter it again to confirm. If I just click "cancel" the git-svn command runs just fine.

Is there a way to completely disable this pinentry-qt tool from my machine ?

Comment: I am having the same problem with regular git. have you found a solution? I know if you hit cancel it goes back to the command line prompts

Comment: No I still do not have a solution to this.  But if I enter a wrong password 2 times in a row, then I cannot connect to the repository anymore. anyway this feature is really annoying

Comment: I agree, I wonder if I can just rig up a LD injection script to simulate a cancel click every time it pops up

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution [here](http://dfspspirit.wordpress.com/2014/07/18/disable-the-pinentry-gui-window-for-ssh-svnssh-gpg-under-linux/#comment-231):

export PINENTRY_USER_DATA="USE_CURSES=1"

unset GPG_AGENT_INFO

You can put this into ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile or a similar file.

Answer (score 0):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/384870/how-can-i-disable-gnome-keyring-for-svn

Edit the ~/.subversion/config, and add the following lines

```
[auth] 
  password-stores =
```